# Check all parameter pack args of function template belong to int

Tags: c++, c++17

I want my function to accept variadic args of type `int` only. For example, to compute sum (taken from C++ core guidelines):

```
template<class ...Args>
auto sum(Args... args) // GOOD, and much more flexible
{
    return (... + args); // note: C++17 "fold expression"
}
```

Taking this simple example from [std::conjunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction) -

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>, int>
control(T, Ts...)
{
    std::cout << "all types in pack are T\n";
    return 0;
}
```

seems to check type T against Ts, which isn't something I want (it will compile successfully if all args of type say `double`).

How do I go about doing that?

Secondly, does the conjunction example split T and Ts just for the purpose of checking types, and it's intended usage is just one set of variadic args? What is this pattern called?

Comment: Just have overloads for what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a variadic function that only accepts a variable amount of `int`s, a fold expression in `std::enable_if` could do that:

```cpp
template<class ...Args>
auto sum(Args... args)
    -> std::enable_if_t<(... && std::is_same_v<Args, int>), int>
// note: It's best to use std::enable_if_t in return types.
//       The actual return type is int here, std::enable_if_t is just wrapping it
//       for the sake of doing SFINAE.
{
    // note: use zero to get a value for empty packs
    return (0 + ... + args);
}
```

Using `std::conjunction` is overkill here, especially since fold expressions get the job done just as well in C++17. And yes, splitting the pack into `T` and `Ts` was only done so that we can compare all `Ts` to the first type via `std::is_same_v<T, Ts>...`.

However, this is *really* questionably design, because:

- this will instantiate separate functions `sum<int>`, `sum<int, int>`, ... (bad for compilation performance)
- we cannot call this function with arguments of type `long` or `float`, because substitution would fail, even if they are constants and we know that converting to `int` is safe

A *much* saner design would be to use `std::initializer_list<int>`:

```cpp
#include <numeric>

int sum(std::initializer_list<int> args)
{
    return std::reduce(args.begin(), args.end());
}

// call with sum({1, 2, 3, 4})
```

Yes, this will require us to use extra braces, but implicit conversions work, and the function is not even a template anymore, making it worth it.

Comment: I could probably live with the function not running with float/long, I'd like to stick with just int.
Your second point is interesting with regards to compile time, wonder why the core guidelines does not point that out in their example: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f55-dont-use-va_arg-arguments
Your initializer list design could work well there too.

Comment: @rookie the main takeaway from that guideline is not to use `va_arg` anyway. The guidelines recommend `std::initializer_list` over variadic function templates here though: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rt-variadic-not

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that section. Definitely makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Hope they add an example there soon

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fold expression in the `enable_if`:

```
template<typename... Args, 
         std::enable_if_t<(... && std::is_same_v<Args, int>), bool> = true>
auto sum(Args... args) // GOOD, and much more flexible
{
    return (... + args); // note: C++17 "fold expression"
}
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Do you mind explaining what `std::enable_if_t<(... && std::is_same_v<Args, int>), bool> = true>` does.

Comment: @rookie The `(... && std::is_same_v<Args, int>)` part checks if each `Args` is an `int` and ands all that together.  If it is true then `std::enable_if_t<(... && std::is_same_v<Args, int>), bool>` become `bool` and we assign `true` to it as a default value so no value needs to be provided by you.  If the condition is false the whole template gets thrown out of consideration